# The last thing I ever wanted to do

Tags: expressions

The last thing I ever wanted to do was pushed away from me.

Would the above sentence be interpreted as:
1. The last thing in life I wanted to do was pushed away from me. 
OR
2. The thing I didn’t want to do was pushed away from me.

Or is unclear? Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: On my first read, I thought it was 2.  Maybe you can change 'last' for 'final'?

Comment: It would be interpreted as confusing, because *"the last thing I ever wanted to do"* is an idiom meaning something you really did not want to do.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what that is supposed to mean.  Suppose I say, “The last thing I wanted to do was offend you.” Now, how does offending you get pushed away from me.

Comment: Or is what you wanf to say, “The last thing I ever wanted to do is push you away from me.”.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct however to make an informed choice on what it means, we would need more context. The sentence could mean both. This is known as 'dual ambiguity' and this confusion is caused by the separation of the clauses. The 'complement' of the sentence 'I wanted to do' is just extra information, but where it placed is causing the confusion. I also think you should replace 'last' with 'final' but that is my opinion.